# Masks not working in Gecko

Tags: firefox, animation, css, webkit

I am trying to mask an element that has some images inside of it, using only css.
i have done this and it works fine in webkit using `-webkit-mask-box-image` and its doing just what i want, but im having trouble using other browsers.

gecko is supposed to work using `mask`, and that tag does show up in firebug, but it doesnt actually use the mask..  i've also tried converting the png im using to base64 data uri, but to no avail.

example:  http://jsfiddle.net/nNLta/

does anyone know the correct way for doing this?

HTML

```
<div id='wrap'>  
        <div class='masked flashing-anim'>  
            <div class='the-mask' >  
                <ul>  
                         <li class='blink_1'></li>  
                        <li class='blink_2'></li> 
                </ul>  
            </div>  
        </div>  
        <div class='the-outline'>  
            <img src='img/real-stuff.png' height=500 />  
        </div>  
        </div>
```

CSS

```
   #wrap {
    position: relative;
   }
   .the-outline, the-mask {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
   } 
   .the-mask {
        height: 500px;
        width: 360px;
        -webkit-mask-box-image: url(../img/the-mask.png);
        -moz-mask-box-image: url(../img/the-mask.png);
        -o-mask-box-image: url(../img/the-mask.png);
        mask-box-image: url(../img/the-mask.png);
        mask: url(data:lotsofchars);
    }
```

example:  http://jsfiddle.net/nNLta/

Answer (score 3):

**Part 1**

`mask` is not the same as `mask-box-image` unfortunately. If you read the (rather sparse) [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/mask) you will see it is applicable to SVG only. More on this later.

Currently Gecko doesn't support 'mask-box-image' - if you [search the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=mask-box) you'll see it applies to -webkit- only.

Additionally I don't think this is actually spec. Webkit has had this capability/concept for ages (in various forms like `-webkit-box-reflect`) and I think that it's just a hangover from those days. I'm not sure whether this will even be adopted by all browser vendors (although I hope, and it makes sense that, it will).

**Part 2**

To use the svg dependant `mask:` css property you need to create an SVG element and reference that. [Here is a guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content#Using_embedded_SVG). I've not used this technique before so I'm afraid that's all the detail I'm going to go into right now.

**An alternate option**

If you don't need a clever repeating/growing mask why not create a large png and overlay the text/image you wish to hide. I'm not sure I understand what you are ultimately trying to do but this seems pretty simple to me. The obvious issue is when you need the stuff behind the mask to be selectable/interactable (err..interactive that is...); for instance when you wish to apply masking to text or links. A way around this is to use `pointer-events:none` which is supported in Gecko and Webkit (but nothing else...). Here's [more from the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events)

Sorry I don't have better news - if none of the above is helpful please feel free to leave a comment with your specific requirement and we'll see if we can't work around the browser limitations.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Indeed, masks are not part of the spec, although [some say](http://caniuse.com/css-masks) that they're being proposed to be standardized. I don't know much about this myself, really.

Comment: actually, the alternative option you suggest seem to me as what i was actually trying to achieve.   what im using this for is a animation typpe thing, and this mask just makes it all 'pretty'.   i guess i would really have to limit this to webkit....or try making an svg for the mask. not much experience though... thanks anyway

Comment: No problem! If the alternate option will work for you, you can achieve this in all browser if layering is not an issue OR in FF, Safari and Chrome if you need to use `pointer-events:none`

Comment: i lost you... no, actually i dont see how pointer-events get into this, AND layering is obviously an issue, since that's how i mask...   its basically one color layer, with a mask, and another layer over that.

Comment: When I say 'issue' I mean that the layer you add causes an issue. If, for example, you are adding a grain over some text but need to be able to select/click the text the layer will get in the way. In this scenario you could use `pointer-events` to enable interacting on the element that's 'beneath' the image layer.

Comment: @inrbob, i dont need the clicks, i just need the layering effect, like in webkit; where i can use a transparent png/gif to mask the object under it. that's the actual problem, and as i sadly realize, i'm going to have to limit this to webkit..

Comment: Cool - I just thought I should be as thorough as possible :). While I've never needed to use `mask-box-image` myself (always managed to get around it using the alternate option I detailed), hopefully this will get included in the spec though - I want it now!